# Passing Parameters in reflections Windows store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, reflection, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to pass some parameters to function that is being called using reflection in a universal windows App. Below is the code which I tried and I am getting an exception "Parameters Count mismatch.". please advice me.

```
public class myClass
{
    public async void btn_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType("moto_Windows.Actions.NextViewAction");                  
        object[] mParam = new object[] { 5, 10 };
        var nva = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        await (dynamic)type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("NextView").Invoke(nva, mParam);
    }
}
```

The class I am trying to invoke look like below

```
namespace moto_Windows.Actions
 {
    public class NextViewAction
    {   
    public NextViewAction(object [] obj)
    {  
         //Constructor         
    }
    public async void NextView()
    {
        //Method to be invoked.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your constructor has required arguments, and you're not passing them. And then for the method, you're passing parameters when the method doesn't have any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this by passing values in a dictionary through a contructor, my code is

```
Type type = Type.GetType("moto.Actions." + ctrl.Action.name);
ctrl = (Carrot_Control)btn.DataContext;
Dictionary<string, object> _dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict.Add("a", 5);
_dict.Add("b", 10);
var t = Activator.CreateInstance(type, _dict);
await (dynamic)type.GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod("NextView").Invoke(t, null);
```

and the class i tried to invoke

```
namespace moto_Windows.Actions
{
public class NextViewAction
{   
public NextViewAction(Dictionary<string,object> _dict)
{  
     //Constructor         
     string a = _dict[a];
     string b = _dict[b];
}
public async void NextView()
{
    //Method to be invoked.
}
}
}
```

please post if anybody has better answer.